# Interface as template parameter

Tags: c++, interface

I have following constructor of a histogram class:

```
Histogram(float start, float end, float bin_size, std::vector<BinnableObject<T>*>* data);
```

And following interface

```
template<typename T>
class BinnableObject
{
public:
    virtual T getBinnableObject() = 0;
};
```

I have a class `Ring` implementing this interface

```
template<class T>
class Ring : BinnableObject<T>
{
public:
    Ring(Point<T> c, T r)
    {
        m_center = c;
        m_radius = r;
    }
    Point<T> m_center;
    T m_radius;

    T getBinnableObject()
    {
        return m_radius;
    }
};
```

Is there way I can call the histogram constructor with a vector of Rings?

```
Histogram<float> h(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f, &data.m_rings);
```

where `&data.m_rings` is `std::vector<Ring<float>*>`

**MCVE below**

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class BinnableObject
{
public:
    virtual T getBinnableObject() = 0;
};



template<class T>
class Ring : public BinnableObject<T>
{
public:
    T m_radius;
    T getBinnableObject()
    {
        return m_radius;
    }
};


template <typename T>
class Histogram
{
public:
    Histogram(float start, float end, float bin_size, std::vector<BinnableObject<T> >* data) {};
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<Ring<float>*> rings;
    Histogram<float> h(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f, &rings);
}
```

Comment: Try calling without explicitly stating type parameters, because `BSE::Histogram<float>` is for a template class, which I assume `Histrogram` isn't. MCVE would be helpful here.

Comment: No. Just make the constructor a template, and don't pass vectors around, pass a pair of iterators like every good citizen. An of course avoid raw pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is related to the fact that `std::vector<Ring<T>>` is in no way related to `std::vector<BinnableObject<T>>` irrespective of the inheritance of `Ring` from `BinnableObject`.

Could you not however make Histogram a templated function/constructor?

i.e.

```
template<class T>
Histogram(float, float, float, std::vector<T>);
```